# Dhtmlx gantt chart parse call taking > 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, optimization, dhtmlx

I'm using the **gantt chart** from **dhtmlx** and running into issues loading large data sets.

Once the data is rendered it works great. There are no performance issues at all.

I've done some profiling and narrowed the bottle neck down to the `gantt.parse()` line in my code. It takes **over 20 seconds** to return.

I have a moderately complex data set, almost 1400 records long.

I've gone through all the optimizing tips I can't find in the documentation, even though they only seem to be around performance tweaking not data loading.

Can you help reduce the time it takes to load my data set?

Comment: Did you find solution for the above problem, If yes means can you share your experience with us.

Comment: I answered my question below with my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The length of a project greatly slows down the load time. There were a few 100 year long projects. clamping down the project length to a reasonable time frame mitigates this load.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2023 (v8 of DHTMLx Gantt charts):

You can improve performance if instead of `gantt.parse(data)` you use:

```
gantt.silent(()=>{gantt.parse(data);});
gantt.render();
```

In my case with a data array of 50k items, this turned a 30minute parse call (!) into 10s (!!!), and another 2s for the `render` call.

Comment: It shouldn't take 30 min to load the data. Most likely, the issue is with the wrong Gantt configuration. 
For example, the combination of the slack calculation with auto-scheduling can take a lot of time with the wrong configuration:
https://forum.dhtmlx.com/t/autoscheduling-performance/75540

Here is an example where 50000 tasks are loaded within 10 second on my computer:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/c8adxcyq

You can reproduce the issue in the snippet and share it. Then I will check if there are ways to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__performance.html

Here are ways to improve the performance of the gantt chart they are pretty simple and documentation is available.

Also, Keep updating the version of the dhtmlxgantt.js as they improve performance in their every releasest too.